# Efficient Database Operation Execution in MassTransit.Worker Across Multiple Servers

Tags: .net, .net-core, architecture, masstransit

I am currently working on a project where I have implemented a `MassTransit.Worker` with a `RabbitMQ` consumer that performs database operations upon receiving messages. The challenge I am facing is related to scaling this system across multiple servers, where each server may have one or more databases, and I want to ensure that database operations are executed only by the worker instance associated with the relevant database.

I have a MassTransit.Worker setup, and the workers are spread across different servers. Each worker instance is capable of executing database operations based on messages received from a RabbitMQ queue. However, the key challenge is dynamically routing messages to the correct worker based on the target database specified in the message.

To clarify, the system has multiple worker instances, each on a different server, and each server may host one or more databases. When a message is sent to the RabbitMQ queue, it contains information about the database on which the operation should be performed. I want to design a system where only the worker instance associated with the specified database processes the message, and all other instances ignore it.

Objective:

Efficiently route messages to the correct worker without having explicit knowledge of worker instances when sending messages.

Design a dynamic system that can handle an arbitrary number of servers and databases without the need for manual configuration.

Design:
[image]

Questions:

1. What would be an effective strategy or pattern to dynamically route messages to the correct worker instance based on the target database?
2. Are there any existing MassTransit features or RabbitMQ configurations that can help achieve this dynamic routing without manual intervention?
3. How can I ensure that the system remains scalable, allowing for the addition of new servers and databases without requiring adjustments to the routing mechanism?